# Cakephp 2.x Security::cipher not providing results across two apps

Tags: php, web-services, curl, cakephp, cakephp-2.x

I have 2 apps communicating with each other. The 1st app is the one who do the transactions and the other app is a settings app to control the 1st app's system settings.

Upon on reaching the login page of the first app, I'm calling a WebService through `curl` inside the `config.php` and it will communicate to the 2nd app and it will return corresponding values. Now, my problem is, the value was encrypted using the `Security::cipher()` function and it was encrypted using a module inside of the settings app. When I try to decrypt it, there is no error prompted and even no error is logged in the error logs file. I suspect that when I decrypt from `WebServicesController` it doesn't read the Security component. I tried to put `App::uses('Security','Utility')` on the top of the codes. Here's how I code it:

1st app

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, Configure::read('TMSWebServices.Url').'getSystemSetting.json');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));

$result_json = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$result = json_decode($result_json, true);
debug($result); exit;
```

2nd app

```
App::uses('AuthComponent', 'Controller/Component');
App::uses('UsersController', 'Controller');
App::uses('Security','Utility');

class WebServicesController extends AppController {
 public $name = 'WebServices';
 public $uses = array('Tenant', 'TbNextId', 'ReportMaster' );
 public $components = array('RequestHandler');

 public function getSystemSetting(){
    $this->loadModel('SystemSetting');
    $results = $this->SystemSetting->find($type, $params);
    $return_value = array();
    $return_value = $results['SystemSetting'];
   foreach($return_value['Config'] as $key=>$value){
        if ($value['ENCRYPT_IND'] == 'Y'){
             $encryptedValue = $return_value['Config'][$key]['SYSTEM_SETTING_VALUE'];
         //decrypt the value
           $decryptedValue = Security::cipher($encryptedValue, 
          Configure::read('Security.salt')); // the problem starts here
           $return_value['Config'][$key]['SYSTEM_SETTING_VALUE'] = $decryptedValue;
        }
   }

 }

}
$this->set(array(
                'return_value' => $return_value,
                '_serialize' => array('return_value')
            ));
```

When I try to just put simple value on the $return_value, the communication works. But if I use the `Security::cipher` to decrypt, it doesn't work and give me a null value. [image]

Comment: Is that really your actual code? Because in that snippet, `$return_value['Config']` cannot be an array, pushing into `$return_value` like `$return_value[] = $results['SystemSetting'];` will create either an array with a single flat item, or a numerically indexed nested one, but certainly not an associative one.

Comment: edited. I'm sorry i forgot to remove the bracket.

Answer (score 0):

I would look at two problems:

1. The `Security.salt` value is *usually not* the same across two CakePHP apps. From your error message I think that it's either empty or not set (i.e. null). Unless you set `Security.salt` to the same value in both apps, `cipher` will not work giving you either null or some incorrect value.
2. As @ndm mentioned in the comment, you are creating a flat array (not an associative array) so I wonder how it is that your code even enters the `foreach` loop.

Look at the following code and my comments:

```
// ... 
$return_value = array(); // we have ourselves an empty array
$return_value[] = $results['SystemSetting']; // we assign a value to $return_value[0]
foreach($return_value['Config'] as $key=>$value){ // no such key 'Config' in the array
// loop code follows, but execution flow shouldn't enter here...
```

While we are at it, I strongly encourage you to **not use `Security.salt`** because it is **just a weak XOR cipher**, try to use [`Security.encrypt()`](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/security.html#Security::encrypt) and [`Security.decrypt()`](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/security.html#Security::decrypt)

Comment: but normally the Configure::read('Security.salt') is read in the 2nd apps and set thru this app only. Should I set it on the 1st app as well?

Comment: I cannot also use the Security.encrypt() and Security.decrypt() because the current apps are using old cakephp version

Comment: Yes, that was my point exactly, you need to first set `Security.salt` to the same value in both apps, and then read it in both apps and pass it to `Security.cipher`

Comment: I have checked my both apps and they are using the same value for the Security.salt

Comment: then retrieve it and provide that as an argument to `cipher` in both apps.

Comment: I used this to read the Security.salt $decryptedValue =Security::cipher($encryptedValue,Configure::read('Security.salt'));